# iMac froze when switched off while updated installation

Tags: imac, software-update

How to restart iMac(~7-8 years old) when i switched off it while it was installing an updated? Can’t press anything now and internet connection is off but can’t  write in a password. Now it shows that-installing on “folder” remains 40min but nothing happens for days? And when I plug out or restart, it stills shows the same.

Comment: It was installing an OS update, or a whole new OS? Which OS version? Turning it off while updating the OS is likely to leave it in a 'broken' state. You've tried Internet Recovery? Do you have a backup you could restore from?

Comment: Whole new Os. When I restart It switches on, downloads at first and then I have a big white field that shows installing in a folder and about 40min remaining. 
I tried booting safe mode with shift, plug it out and press for a long time switch off button. But everything is the same. I don’t have  backup and don’t know got the recover internet

Comment: Internet Recovery is described here. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl338cf9a8/mac But you must be very careful if you have no backup. ALWAYS keep another copy of your files, if you don't want to lose them.

Comment: I plugged internet with a wire but still nothing changes. On this computer I don’t have any data that is important, therefore I don’t care about the backup.

Comment: Have you tried holding down option-command-r while booting with network plugged in?

Comment: Yes, but later on it looked like it’s updating but then it restarts with the black screen and small Apple logo with the line when it’s loading to switch on but it stops in the middle and nothing happens anymore.